# qualification constraints and Slater's condition

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I'm considering the following minimization problem:
$$ \begin{cases} min f(x) \\ s.t.\ \ \ \ g_{i}(x)\le0 & x \in R^n, i \in I={1,..m} & f,g_{i} \in C^1
\end{cases} \\ $$

Given  $x \in S $ where S is the feasible region

$ Set: \\   D1(\bar x)=\{d \in R^n : \exists  \alpha>0 : x+\alpha d \in S   \}\\
I(\bar x)=\{i \in I: g_{i}(\bar x)=0 \}
\\ D2(\bar x)=\{d \in R^n : \nabla^tg_{i}d \le0  \hspace{0.2 cm}  \forall i \in I(\bar x) \} \\ $

We say that the qualification constraint (QC) holds at $\bar x$ if $ D1(\bar x)=D2(\bar x)  $.

Now, according to my notes, if the $g_{i}$'s are convex and there exixsts a point $\alpha$ s.t. $g_{i}(\alpha)<0$ $ \forall i$ then the QC holds.  I'm having some trouble with this last part. If a function is convex then the lower contours are convex sets so if, for istance, I take only one constraint, say: $g=x^2 + y^2-3, $ which is convex, then the feasible region is a disk and for each point of the circle the tangent t belongs to D2 but not to D1. So I'm thinking that maybe the $g_{i}$ must be concave or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The feasible region in your example is the entire disc, not just the circle. Are you dealing with affine $g_i$ by any chance? The condition GC will not hold on the boundary of the disc because $D_1$ is fairly restrictive.

Comment: I've corrected the mistake, thanks. No, the $ g_{i} $ are generic $ C^1 $ functions.

Comment: Are you sure that the inequality in the definition of $D_2$ is not strict?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Indeed my notes give the following example of a case in which $D_1 \subset D_2$. The constraints are $g_1=-x_1$,  $g_2=-x_2$, $g_3=-(1-x_1)^3+x_2$. and the problem is in (1,0) where the gradient of $g_3$ is orthogonal to the $(\alpha,0)$ direction which is not feasible.

Comment: Ok, the QC was wrong. QC holds if $ \bar{D_1} (\bar x) =D_2(\bar x)$. This should solve the issue.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Are you dealing with convex functions?